# Hide area outside of axis in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

How can I extend the plot area to take up the whole canvas and essentially remove the gray area in the image? I've looked around and I haven't found any solutions, although maybe it's because I don't know what to call that area so searching is challenging.

Using `fig.tight_layout()` reduces the gray but does not remove it.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

y = [1,3,5,6,7,8,12,13,15,15,16,25,26,28,29,36]
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4), dpi=85)

ax.stackplot(x, y, color='w', colors=('#ededed',))

ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.set_ylim([0,max(y)*1.2])
ax.set_xlim([0,30])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I believe if you save the file (as .png, or .pdf) they grey is all gone.  Use plt.savefig('output_name.pdf') to do it.

Comment: @TravisJ. You are correct, but I'm not trying to get a file out of it, I am dumping it in a Tkinter window.

Answer (score 1):

Specify that the `Axes` take up the whole `Figure` when you create the `Axes` --

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes((0,0,1,1), frameon=False)
ax.plot([2,5,4])
```

[image]

now, there's a lot there isn't room for any more, e.g. external tick labels; and Tkinter may be doing some padding itself; but this is as large as you can make an `Axes`. ( `(0,0,1,1)` is extent in Figure coordinates.)