# matplotlib: remove all figure margin around ax, then show

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Other answers on this site discuss how to remove "whitespace" margins around matplotlib plots when saving a figure to disk with `fig.savefig()`. None seem to show how to do this for *displaying* the figure with `plt.show()` rather than saving it.

How do I remove the gray around the following figure (without saving it to disk)?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='gray')
ax.set_facecolor('pink')
ax.scatter([5, 1, 3], [1, 2, 3], s=100, c='b')

ax.axis('on')
ax.margins(0)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.tick_params(which="both", direction="in")
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

fig.subplots_adjust(0, 0, 1, 1)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Above, the gray margin of the figure remains around the pink ax, no matter what I do. Below, I can remove it when saving to disk:

```py
extent = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
fig.savefig('test.jpg', facecolor='gray', bbox_inches=extent)
```

[image]

This is the image I want to "show." But I can find nothing to re-create that `bbox_inches=extent` functionality outside of the `savefig` function. So how do I remove the gray around the plot and then show it with `plt.show`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a simple solution using the argument `frameon=False` while creating the axis instance as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29738811/4932316) answer

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='gray', frameon=False)
```

which produces the following with `plt.show()`.

EDIT: I also now remove the axes around the figure using the following

```
for spine in ['top', 'right', 'left', 'bottom']:
    ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
```

or as a one-liner:

```
_ = [s.set_visible(False) for s in ax.spines.values()]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Almost there... how do you remove the black line border around your image? It looks like `ax.set_frame_on(False)` removes the pink background too.

Comment: Great. Upvoted and accepted. Adapted as a one-liner, I ended up using `[s.set_visible(False) for s in ax.spines.values()]`